# Getting more precise PSNR from ffmpeg filter

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible with ffmpeg psnr filter to get a psnr measurement with more than 2 digits?

for example

```
ffmpeg -i video1.yuv-i video2.yuv -lavfi psnr=stats_file=psnr_stats.txt -f null -
```

psnr_stats.txt looks like:

```
n:1 mse_avg:131.63 mse_y:198.03 mse_u:45.96 mse_v:84.51 psnr_avg:38.99 psnr_y:37.23 psnr_u:43.57 psnr_v:40.93 
n:2 mse_avg:153.95 mse_y:236.57 mse_u:49.66 mse_v:93.00 psnr_avg:38.31 psnr_y:36.46 psnr_u:43.24 psnr_v:40.51
```

Is it possible to make it output more than 2 decimal digits?

PS: I need to work with > 8 bits videos, therefore tools that compute PSNR with 255 as max are not suitable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: Printouts are no longer limited to 2 figures after the decimal point as of 12th Feb 2021. Available in git master builds or starting with release 4.4

---

More precise figures don't look possible. All the data printout formats are hardcoded as `"%0.2f"` in `libavfilter/vf_psnr.c`.